# Character codes (locale) for text in Skype for Business Bot

Tags: localization, botframework, skype-for-business

I'm developing a Bot for a Brazilian customer.
I've been translating all text to this language, and it seems it's done.
I deployed the bot to be used as a web chat, using direct line, and it's running fine.
Last days I was working to have it running on SFB, and today I finally complete it. However, I found some issues with "special" characters (from the brazilian alphabet), and I'm unable to fix it.

I mean, by instance, instead of showing "Não está cadastrado seu e-mail." it's showing "N?o est? cadastrado seu e-mail." If I use Web Chat or Skype as channel, the text is displayed property.

Is there a way to solve this issue? I've already try to "HTMLEncode" the text, but that did not work either.

Update 07/14: Added sample images, same text, one displayed in a web chat, the other, in SFB.

[image: Web Chat]

[image: SFB chat]

Thank you in advance

Update 08-01:
Hello, it seems MS solved the problem. Today I started over my testing with my brazilian customer, and I could see that all "strange" characters now are being displayed properly. 
See the image below:

[image: SFB Chat]